# New To GWT Need Help with Error

Tags: gwt

I am new to GWT and my program was compiling fine until now when I am trying to add a calendar with round corners using rico.js. What doest this error mean and what should I be looking for?

This is also happening ONLY IN FIREFOX (I have 4.0.1)

```
[ERROR] Line 105: No source code is available for type com.packtpub.gwtbook.widgets.util.Rico; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

Thank you

Here is the trace also

```
06:12:04.812 [ERROR] [Samples] Uncaught exception escaped

com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: One or more exceptions caught, see full set in UmbrellaException#getCauses
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:129)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.HistoryImpl.fireEvent(HistoryImpl.java:76)
    at com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeEvent.fire(ValueChangeEvent.java:43)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.HistoryImpl.fireHistoryChangedImpl(HistoryImpl.java:83)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.HistoryImpl.newItem(HistoryImpl.java:127)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.History.newItem(History.java:169)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.History.newItem(History.java:154)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Hyperlink.onBrowserEvent(Hyperlink.java:285)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1321)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1277)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:167)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:326)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:207)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:132)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:214)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor16.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:167)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:281)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:531)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError): $wnd.Rico is undefined
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:237)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:132)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeVoid(ModuleSpace.java:289)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeVoid(JavaScriptHost.java:107)
    at com.packtpub.gwtbook.widgets.client.util.Rico.corner(Rico.java)
    at com.packtpub.gwtbook.widgets.client.CalendarWidget.&lt;init&gt;(CalendarWidget.java:104)
    at com.packtpub.gwtbook.samples.client.panels.CalendarWidgetPanel.&lt;init&gt;(CalendarWidgetPanel.java:27)
    at com.packtpub.gwtbook.samples.client.panels.CalendarWidgetPanel$1.createInstance(CalendarWidgetPanel.java:17)
    at com.packtpub.gwtbook.samples.client.SamplePanel$SinkInfo.getInstance(SamplePanel.java:35)
    at com.packtpub.gwtbook.samples.client.Samples.show(Samples.java:98)
    at com.packtpub.gwtbook.samples.client.Samples.onHistoryChanged(Samples.java:45)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.BaseListenerWrapper$WrapHistory.onValueChange(BaseListenerWrapper.java:89)
    at com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeEvent.dispatch(ValueChangeEvent.java:128)
    at com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeEvent.dispatch(ValueChangeEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.GwtEvent.dispatch(GwtEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:193)
    at com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:88)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:127)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.HistoryImpl.fireEvent(HistoryImpl.java:76)
    at com.google.gwt.event.logical.shared.ValueChangeEvent.fire(ValueChangeEvent.java:43)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.HistoryImpl.fireHistoryChangedImpl(HistoryImpl.java:83)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.impl.HistoryImpl.newItem(HistoryImpl.java:127)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.History.newItem(History.java:169)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.History.newItem(History.java:154)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Hyperlink.onBrowserEvent(Hyperlink.java:285)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1321)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1277)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:167)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:326)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:207)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:132)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:214)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor16.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:167)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:281)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:531)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Is the external package rico.js wrapped in gwt or is it just plain js? If its a wrapper, see if you have included the module in your <proj>.gwt.xml file. If its plain js, see if you have added the script tag in the html file. If neither, then we will need to see the code.

Comment: Bhat - Post this an answer this solved my problem. When you do I will mark it and give you a vote too :). Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the external package rico.js wrapped in gwt or is it just plain js? If its a wrapper, see if you have included the module in your .gwt.xml file. If its plain js, see if you have added the script tag in the html file. If neither, then we will need to see the code